# DC motor limits

Tags: motor, dc-motor, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

I bought a 12V 35W DC motor, 50RPM, 15kg.fcm of torque.

As it should, when it has a low load it absorbs only a couple of hundred mA.

Can I raise the voltage on the motor without exceeding 35W since I'm trying to achieve a greater speed ?

Link to the motor: https://a.aliexpress.com/_mLu9gbH

Comment: 'kg' is a measure of mass, not torque which is measured in Nm (newton-meters). [Edit] the question to include a link to the datasheet. Raising the voltage will increase the speed beyond its design ratings and will result in proportionally higher starting current. Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That line of motors has a wide range of speeds available (different gearheads). You just need to pick a different model.

Comment: What is the maximum voltage specified in the motor data sheet. If you can't find a data sheet then it's quite likely that the item you have bought from aliexpress is pretty low quality. Ditto ebay, shamazon, bang-good etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have bought a '35 W' motor, that means it's rated to produce 35 Watts mechanical output power under rated conditions. It's not a limit on how much electrical energy you can or should supply.

If supplied with the rated voltage, the motor will run at rated speed. If you supply a higher voltage, it will run faster. This will shorten the life of the bearings and the commutator, which is important in a high reliability application, and may be irrelevant in your application. When I was building BattleBots, the lifetime of the motor could be minutes, and it was common among builders to over-volt motors by 50% for the extra speed. With enough extra speed, the armature could mechanically burst, as centripetal force varies as the speed squared. Apply the voltage that meets your requirements.

The rated current will heat the windings, and at rated speed, enough cooling will be generated to dissipate this without an excessive temperature rise. If you load the motor with excess torque, it will generate much more heat (heat goes as torque or current squared). Even if you run the motor at rated torque, if you run it slow, it may not stir the air inside around enough to cool the armature properly.

Answer (score 2):

As you have observed, the current is proportional to the torque required by the load. Speed is proportional to voltage, so increasing the voltage will increase the speed. Since the losses in the motor are mostly proportional to current, you can probably increase the speed somewhat without overheating the motor. The increase in power can be supplied by the motor to the extent that the current does not exceed the rated current of the motor.

Increasing the speed of a motor above the nominal speed can often provide "free" power increase. It will shorten the life of the motor by increasing the friction wear, but it can often be done without causing short-term harm to the motor. However inexpensive hobby motors probably don't have a very long life expectancy to begin with.

The motor has a built-in speed-reducing gear. That has quite a bit of friction loss. That will not increase the torque very much as speed increases, but it will increase the power.

Comment: Can you tell me whether brushless DC motors will be affected too much if the applied voltage is increased?

Comment: A brushless DC motor will generally perform similarly to a commutator motor. However the motor controller will likely be less tolerant of voltage increase.